# What is the highest altitude for riding a broomstick?

Tags: harry-potter, flying-brooms

What is the highest altitude a witch or wizard can ride a broomstick? Do they provide some magic to protect the rider from altitude sickness? Of course this is not a problem in England, but it could be interesting to know if you could cross the Himalayas.

Comment: I have been [reliably informed](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/The_Quibbler) that you can fly to the [Moon](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Moon) on a Cleansweep 6. It's surprising that they haven't used that in their advertising.

Comment: Other manga about wizard I know. Youjo Senki. Normal wizard flight around 4000m. Trained wizard from 6000-8000m. Best wizard like 10000m.

So yes technically they can cross Himalayas

Comment: Very high, so long as you solve the [Icing Problem](https://youtu.be/CamVRgvcp28?t=85).

Answer (score -1):

We know that broomstick have altitude limits, above which they become uncontrollable.

> The Moontrimmer, which was first created by Gladys Boothby in 1901, represented a leap forward in broom construction, and for a while these slender, ash-handled brooms were in great demand as Quidditch brooms. The Moontrimmer’s principal advantage over other brooms was its ability to achieve greater heights than ever before (and remain controllable at such altitudes) Source: Quidditch Through the Ages, Chapter 9 (The Development of the Racing Broom)

We also know that enchantments are used to enable brooms to fly.

> ‘What’s that Weasley’s riding?’ Malfoy called in his sneering drawl. ‘Why would anyone put a flying charm on a mouldy old log like that? Source: Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 14 (Percy and Padfoot)

Based on these quotes, we can deduce that brooms are enchanted to fly like birds, so maybe if the charms cannot produce enough lift, the wizard or witch cannot fly.

But brooms and other flying objects like vehicles behave like animals, so maybe the charms have limits, and if brooms are flown higher than the animals the charms are based on, they become less controllable until they cannot be flown at all.